# Conditionally calculate time differences between rows in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between a row and a row that has a column that meets some criteria.

Reading in some data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(criteria = c("some text", "some more text", " ", " ", "more text", " "),
                  timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("2015-07-30 15:53:15", "2015-07-30 15:53:47", "2015-07-30 15:54:48", "2015-07-30 15:55:48", "2015-07-30 15:56:48", "2015-07-30 15:57:49")))

        criteria           timestamp
1      some text 2015-07-30 15:53:15
2 some more text 2015-07-30 15:53:47
3                2015-07-30 15:54:48
4                2015-07-30 15:55:48
5      more text 2015-07-30 15:56:48
6                2015-07-30 15:57:49
```

I want to get the time difference (in minutes) between every row and the last row that wasn't blank in the criteria column. Therefore, I want:

```
        criteria           timestamp time_diff
1      some text 2015-07-30 15:53:15         0
2 some more text 2015-07-30 15:53:47         0
3                2015-07-30 15:54:48         1
4                2015-07-30 15:55:48         2
5      more text 2015-07-30 15:56:48         0
6                2015-07-30 15:57:49         1
```

So far, I've built the code to recognize where the "0's" should be - I just need the code to fill in the time differences. Here's my code:

```
my_data$time_diff <- ifelse (my_data$criteria != "", # Here's our statement
  my_data$time_diff <- "0", # Here's what happens if statement is TRUE
  my_data$time_diff <- NEED CODE HERE # if statement FALSE
  )
```

I have a feeling that this job may be better performed by something that isn't an `ifelse` statement, but i'm relatively new to R.

I've found q's on here where individuals tried to get time differences between neighboring rows (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999460/how-to-calculate-time-difference-between-a-row-and-previous-row-of-a-data-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505879/date-time-differences-between-rows-in-r)), but have yet to find someone trying to deal with this kind of situation.

The closest question I've found to mine is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307781/calculate-time-difference-between-certain-events-in-r), but that data are different from mine in how the individual wants to process them (at least from my vantage point).

edit: capitalized title.

Comment: It seems that for each "timestamp" you need the time difference from the "timestamp"s at `cummax((my_data$criteria != " ") * seq_len(nrow(my_data)))` repsectively?

Comment: @alexis_laz, I think so. To clarify what you mean, i'm comparing each timestamp (e.g. "timestamp3") against the timestamp of the largest row number _above "timestamp3"_ where `my_data$criteria != " " ` . Is that reading correct? If so, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the answer with alexis_laz's masterful expression:

```
my_data <- data.frame(criteria = c("some text", "some more text", " ", " ", "more text", " "),
                      timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("2015-07-30 15:53:15", "2015-07-30 15:53:47", "2015-07-30 15:54:48", "2015-07-30 15:55:48", "2015-07-30 15:56:48", "2015-07-30 15:57:49")))

my_data$time_diff <- 
  my_data$timestamp - 
  my_data[cummax((my_data$criteria != " ") * seq_len(nrow(my_data))), 'timestamp']

my_data

        criteria           timestamp time_diff
1      some text 2015-07-30 15:53:15    0 secs
2 some more text 2015-07-30 15:53:47    0 secs
3                2015-07-30 15:54:48   61 secs
4                2015-07-30 15:55:48  121 secs
5      more text 2015-07-30 15:56:48    0 secs
6                2015-07-30 15:57:49   61 secs
```

Comment: Just as an extra note, `difftime` could be handy here too, with its `units = "mins"` argument